# pgrep not available on AIX

Tags: grep, process, aix

On AIX, I get

```
pgrep -lf ora_pmon
ksh: pgrep:  not found.
```

Does anybody know how to change the code so that it doesn't use `pgrep`?
This is the result on another operating system:

```
pgrep -lf ora_pmon
4104 ora_pmon_dbpicsr
5092 ora_pmon_dbpiss2r
14393 ora_pmon_dbpiss1r
```

I need the code for AIX with that result.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is too old to answer (first time answering a question), but the AIX equivalent you're looking for is

```
ps -ef | awk '$NF~/[o]ra_pmon/ {print $2,$NF}'
```

e.g.

```
[oracle@aixbox ]$ ps -ef | awk '$NF~/[o]ra_pmon/ {print $2,$NF}'
8061108 ora_pmon_XXX
38993950 ora_pmon_YYY
```

Answer (score 1):

you can run

```
ps -ef | grep ora_pmon | grep -v grep
```

and it will give you the process listings that you need. You can simplify this output by using very basic `sed` or `awk` commands, according to your needs.